# OpenCVs BlobDetector crashes

Tags: python, image, image-processing, opencv

I'm trying to use OpenCV's `SimpleBlobDetector`. I'm using a very siple code, I read the image, I create the detector and I apply it. But when I excecute it I get the error `Python has stopped working`.

- The image is properly read
- Is a 1536x2048 image (too big?)
- Could the PGN format be a problem?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np;

# Read image
im = cv2.imread("vlcsnap-2020-02-05-10h54m17s200.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Set up the detector with default parameters.
detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector()

# Detect blobs.
keypoints = detector.detect(im) #No error if I coment this line
```

Does anyone have a clue of why would't this work?

Comment: be sure that you read the image correctly

Comment: I'm sure the image is read correctly => in variable explorer : Type uint8 size (1536, 2048) and I can use other OpenCV functions as `cv2.imshow("Keypoints", im)`

Comment: Always view each step of your processing. See cv2.imshow(im) and cv2.waitKey(0)

Comment: @fmw42 I did, the image is fine

Comment: You need to set up your parameters first with params = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params(). See my answer below.

Comment: It seems like this is more of a python issue rather than an opencv issue. I'm assuming this is Windows. Could you give us the full error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an answer that I posted some time ago in Python/OpenCV for doing blob analysis. Perhaps this will help you.

Input:

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import math

# read image
img = cv2.imread("particles.jpg")

# convert to grayscale
gray=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# apply Gaussian Blur
smoothed = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (0,0), sigmaX=9, sigmaY=9, borderType = cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)

# do adaptive threshold on gray image
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(smoothed, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 65, 10)

cv2.imshow("Threshold", thresh)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# Set up the SimpleBlobdetector with default parameters.
params = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()

# Change thresholds
params.minThreshold = 0
params.maxThreshold = 256

# Filter by Area.
params.filterByArea = True
params.minArea = 30
params.maxArea = 10000

# Filter by Color (black=0)
params.filterByColor = True
params.blobColor = 0

# Filter by Circularity
params.filterByCircularity = True
params.minCircularity = 0.5
params.maxCircularity = 1

# Filter by Convexity
params.filterByConvexity = True
params.minConvexity = 0.5
params.maxConvexity = 1

# Filter by InertiaRatio
params.filterByInertia = True
params.minInertiaRatio = 0
params.maxInertiaRatio = 1

# Distance Between Blobs
params.minDistBetweenBlobs = 0

# Do detecting
detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(params)

# Get keypoints
keypoints = detector.detect(thresh)

print(len(keypoints))
print('')

# Get keypoint locations and radius
for keypoint in keypoints:
   x = int(keypoint.pt[0])
   y = int(keypoint.pt[1])
   s = keypoint.size
   r = int(math.floor(s/2))
   print (x,y,r)
   #cv2.circle(img, (x, y), r, (0, 0, 255), 2)

# Draw blobs
blobs = cv2.drawKeypoints(thresh, keypoints, np.array([]), (0,0,255), cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)
cv2.imshow("Keypoints", blobs)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# Save result
cv2.imwrite("particle_blobs.jpg", blobs)
```

[image]